# Move directory from existing Git repository to a new repository maintaining history and minizing size

Tags: git

**Scenario:** a large Git repository (~16k commits) with many branches, binary files etc. A tool inside `<repo>/a/b` has grown so much that I want to have it's code in a separate repository. I want the history preserved. I am only interested in the history of one branch and the code inside a single directory.

Here is what I did:

```
$ git clone <old git repo>
$ git remote rm origin
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <directory I want> -- --all
```

The result is what I wanted - ~80 commits, one branch and about 10 source files.

**The problem:** the repository is huge. Git gc does not help much.

```
$ du -sh .
904M    .

$ git gc && du -sh .
617M    .

$ cd .. && mkdir tmp && cd tmp && git clone ../repo && du -sh repo
615M    repo/
```

What am I missing? How can I get the repo to a sane size?

Comment: My guess would be that merges pull in unwanted change sets :-/ Can you try to export the changes as patches with history?

Answer (score 2):

Git [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) had a solution to the size problem:

```
$ git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now
$ du -sh .
2.1M   .
```

I also noticed that all the existing tags were unneeded and removed those (before running the above) with:

```
$ for t in $(git tag -l|xargs); do git tag -d $t; done
```

After that I just added a remote pointing to an empty remote repository and pushed there.